# Symfony FOSRestBundle routing multi words controller name

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using the Symfony framework (3.3) and the bundle FOSRestBundle for my web application.

I have a controller named `FooBarsController` and I want to use the "[Automatic route generation: single RESTful controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html)".

The problem is, as you can see, the controller is multi-words compound.

Do I have to annotate my controller classes and methods to map URL like "/foo-bars" :

```php
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Delete;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Post;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Put;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;

/** 
 * @Route("/foo-bars", defaults={"_format": "json"})
 */
class FooBarsController extends FOSRestController
{
    /** 
     * @Get()
     * @View(templateVar="fooBars")
     */
    protected $getFooBarsAction();

    /** 
     * @Get("/{id}", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     * @View(templateVar="fooBar")
     */
    protected $getFooBarAction($id);

    /** 
     * @Post()
     * @View(templateVar="fooBar")
     */
    protected $postFooBarsAction();

    /** 
     * @Put("/{id}", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     * @View(templateVar="fooBar")
     */
    protected $putFooBarAction($id);

    /** 
     * @Delete("/{id}", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     * @View(templateVar="fooBar")
     */
    protected $deleteFooBarAction($id);
}
```

It works fine like this, but I think I'm loosing the force of auto routing.

#### Edit

Here is part of my routing configuration file:

```yml
foo-bars:
    type:     rest
    resource: FooBundle\Controller\FooBarsController
```

Comment: Can you post your routing configuration?

Comment: I added the routing configuration in the question.

Comment: I found and applied this "solution" :
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1726